# I am trying to add a background colour to my game window but it does not work and an attribute error keeps popping up. Any advice?

Tags: python, colors, pygame, background, rgb

```py
import pygame

# Initialise pygame
pygame.init()

# Create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))

# Title
screen = pygame.display.set_caption("Lunar Dungeon")

# Icon Here
icon = pygame.image.load('moon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Game loop

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Background colour - RGB
    screen.fill((0, 0, 128))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\abulr\Downloads\1 Project\Lunar-Dungeon\main.py", line 25, in 
> screen.fill((0, 0, 128))
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fill'

Comment: try `pygame.display.set_caption("Lunar Dungeon")` instead of `screen = pygame.display.set_caption("Lunar Dungeon")`. I suspect that `set_caption` returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove change

<s>`screen = pygame.display.set_caption("Lunar Dungeon")`</s>

```py
pygame.display.set_caption("Lunar Dungeon")
```

The return value of [`pygame.display.set_caption`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_caption) is `None`. This overwrites the variable `screen`, which was set with `pygame.display.set_mode`.